# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views

Tags: sql, t-sql

I get this error:
**The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.**
on the code below, when trying to order from view. How do I fix this?

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_FCoord]
AS
SELECT     FeatId, ISNULL(MLNumber, '') AS MLNumber,
                          (SELECT     Text
                            FROM          dbo.tblFType AS ft
                            WHERE      (FTypeId = dbo.tblFeat.FTypeId)) AS FType, Height, Width, Depth, ISNULL(Description, '') AS Description, 
                                 Latitude, Longitude * - 1 AS Longitude, IsSubsidence, ISNULL(ProjectName, '') 
                      AS ProjectName, ISNULL
                          ((SELECT     Text
                              FROM         dbo.tblFStatusType AS fst
                              WHERE     (FStatusTypeId = dbo.tblFeat.FStatusTypeId)), 'Not Set') AS FStatus, ISNULL
                          ((SELECT     Text
                              FROM         dbo.tblSGType AS st
                              WHERE     (SGTypeId = dbo.tblFeat.SGTypeId)), 'Not Set') AS SGType, SGIsBackfillMaterial, SGDate, 
                      ISNULL(SGDetails, '') AS SGDetails, SGCost, SGIsBatCompatible,
                      (Select COUNT(*) from tblProjectFeat pf where pf.FeatId=dbo.tblFeat.FeatId) NumProjects 
FROM         dbo.tblFeat
WHERE     (Latitude > 0) AND (Longitude > 0)
order by NumProjects asc
GO
```

Comment: You can't make an ordered view of the data, the best you can do is select from your view and then order the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify the `ORDER BY` clause in a view. Create the view without the `ORDER BY` and specify the `ORDER BY` clause when you're selecting from the view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_FCoord]
...
GO


SELECT
    *
FROM vw_FCoord
ORDER BY NumProjects ASC
```

Comment: The reasoning for this is often pragmatic - views are more to get a collected entity of some sort, but how it must be sorted depends on who's asking.  Since an `ORDER BY` is likely to added whenever the view is called, with a _different_ set of columns, it'd be asking the optimizer to perform work that's unnecessary (simply thrown out).  So, prevent the developer from making the db do work it won't care about...